# "rowspan" behavior with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Given this markup :

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.foo {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.b {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}

.c {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJy66/1/)

Is there a way to put the red box in the previous row stream ? I would like to avoid modifying the markup.

The idea here is that the elements should have different layouts between portrait and landscape mode, and that the only way to do it in CSS-only is to use flexbox with the `order` property. As far as I know, using an intermediate element would lock its children.

Comment: not sure i understand what you look for is this you are trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/pJy66/2/ but it is not flex

Answer (score 23):

is this what you are looking for?

```
.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

.a, .c {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: green;
}

.b {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  order: 1;
  background: blue;
}
.c {
  background: red;
}
```

[Quick codepen sample](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/OPRPRR) with -webkit- prefixes

**UPDATE**! [Tuned pen](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/zxKvJR) with landscape/portrait ratios

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without setting a height on .foo?

Comment: This answer is fantastic, do you know if there as an answer that can accommodate an arbitrary number of spanned rows?

Comment: @J__ I think you can write some js that counts the elements and dimensions of the target, but I'm not sure if you can manage it only with css.

Comment: Veiko: How would I go about applying this on a <table>? Reason being, that I need to use a traditional table for js-sorting reasons, and therefore I can't use more than 1 <tr> per "listing"

Comment: @Andreyu You can't do it without height, so it's basically useless... better use float, tables or grid (but lacks support)

Comment: How do we do it when we want to do row-span in the first column

Answer (score 0):

Just add position and bottom to that c element.

**css**

```
.foo {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.b {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}

.c {
    flex: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    bottom:100px;
}
```