# How to create a variable size tile layout in html

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

I'm experimenting to see if I can created a variable sized tile layout like the one below, without any intermediate wrapper `divs`.

[image: Xbox 350 movies and tv home screen]

I first tried a flexbox approach, and then discovered that flexbox isn't designed to have children move across rows, and then and a normal `inline-block` and `float: left` approach, but with the exact same problem. I haven't been able to get the blocks to move across different rows and into the space in between them.

I'm also looking for a no javascript approach. So without using something like Masonry.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/faichenshing/pen/mAxAoW)

It's important for me to point out that I'm trying to solve this problem *generally*, meaning that although we could certainly find a way to create this *particular* layout, I'm more worried about figuring out how to create layouts of this general type, where I might not know ahead of time the exact orientation, order, or size of the tiles.

Here's the desired `html` (`jade`):

```
.xbox-tiles
    .tile 1 x 1
    .tile 1 x 1
    .big-tile 2 x 2
    .tile 1 x 1
    .tile 1 x 1
    .tile 1 x 1
    .tile 1 x 1
    .tile 1 x 1
    .tile 1 x 1
```

and `sass`:

```
@import "bourbon"

%tile
    @include flex(0)
    @include flex-basis(auto)

    // display: inline-block
    // float: left

    box-sizing: border-box


.xbox-tiles
    @include display(flex)
    @include flex-direction(column)
    @include flex-flow(wrap)

    height: 90vh
    width: 90vw

    .tile
        height: 33.33%
        width: 25%
        @extend %tile

    .big-tile
        height: 66.66%
        width: 50%
        @extend %tile
```

Comment: Flexbox can't do that without nested containers.  I suspect Masonry.js might be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm aware of Masonry, but looking for a pure css solution. If it's absolutely not possible you're welcome to submit that as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["rowspan" behavior with flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895011/rowspan-behavior-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22895011/5187323) I was able to produce this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jrmoser/pen/vXjEJY) which uses simple floats, no flexbox needed, in other words float all the small tiles left and the big one right:

```
@import "bourbon"

%tile    
    box-sizing: border-box

.xbox-tiles

    height: 90vh
    width: 90vw

    .tile
        float: left
        height: 33.33%
        width: 25%
        @extend %tile

    .big-tile
        float: right
        height: 66.66%
        width: 50%
        @extend %tile
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.xbox-tiles .tile, .xbox-tiles .big-tile {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
}

.xbox-tiles {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.xbox-tiles .tile {
  float: left;
  height: 33.33%;
  width: 25%;
}
.xbox-tiles .big-tile {
  float: right;
  height: 66.66%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="xbox-tiles">
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 1</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 2</div>
  <div class="big-tile">2 x 2 - 3</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 4</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 5</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 6</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 7</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 8</div>
  <div class="tile">1 x 1 - 9</div>
</div>
```